# Selenium cannot find element on website (chrome/Java)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, authentication

Trying to test/learn selenium to login
the error - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

```
package com.indeed.tests;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
        "C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\neww\\trainingfiles\\chromedriver.exe.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.neopets.com/login/index.phtml");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("test1");
    }
    private static void sleep(int i) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic? (Also, you're not closing brackets, so there's no way your posted code will compile.)

Comment: thanks for the tip, edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at that web page. The problem is that there are two input fields with the name "username". One of them is not visible. Probably Selenium is getting that one. What you should do is:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(...);
```

and then get the second one (or the first, whatever), then try:

```
elements.get(1).sendKeys(...);
```

Comment: thanks this definitely seems to be the problem, if i click on the top "log in" it fills in the info, so I can .click() on the "log in" element first and it will work, however the "log in" has no class or name associated with it when I inspect it, do you know how I could .click() on that element?